# How can I generate script of database by using backup file (.bak)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to generate portable script file of a SQL Server database by using backup (`.bak`) so that we will be able to create database (with all objects and data) without backup file.

I don't want to restore backup file to SQL Server Management Studio to achieve it.

Is it possible?

How can I achieve it?

Comment: You *could* look at tools like [Red-Gate SQL Object Level Recovery Native](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-olr-native/) that allow you to peek into `.bak` files. But without some extra tools, there's no way around **restoring** that database from the `.bak` before you can use it

Answer (score 3):

Follow the normal procedure to restore DB then on the last screen generate script rather than clicking OK:

[image: Restore]

Then you can use the same script or modify it to do what you are after.

Comment: It will only create a script to restore .bak file but i wants script of database so that .bak file never needed.

Comment: In that case you will need to have a look at other tools like the one which is suggested in the comment above.